# Incorrect permissions when running Heroku PHP project locally with Foreman in Ubuntu

Tags: php, ubuntu, heroku, nginx, fastcgi

I have a Heroku PHP project in my local directory in Xubuntu 14.04 machine.

I want to run it locally in order to develop/test it before deploying on Heroku.

First of all, I've tried to cd into project directory and ran `foreman start web`.

There were errors related to some missing packages and PHP version so I did the following:

1). Installed latest PHP version from custom PPA (*ppa:ondrej/php5*):

`php --version`

`PHP 5.5.18-1+deb.sury.org~trusty+1 (cli) (built: Oct 17 2014 15:20:47)`.

2). Created a symlink for `php5-fpm` binary:

`sudo ln -s /usr/sbin/php5-fpm /usr/local/bin/php-fpm`

3). Installed **nginx**.

4). Changed the **Procfile**:

`web: vendor/bin/heroku-php-nginx /web`

Next, I'm trying to start the server using: `foreman start web` command and I'm getting the following output:

```
02:38:23 web.1  | started with pid 15815
02:38:23 web.1  | Booting on port 5000...
02:38:23 web.1  | DOCUMENT_ROOT changed to '/web/'
02:38:24 web.1  | Starting php-fpm...
02:38:24 web.1  | Starting nginx...
02:38:24 web.1  | [06-Nov-2014 02:38:24] NOTICE: [pool www] 'user' directive is ignored when FPM is not running as root
02:38:24 web.1  | [06-Nov-2014 02:38:24] NOTICE: [pool www] 'user' directive is ignored when FPM is not running as root
02:38:26 web.1  | nginx: [alert] could not open error log file: open() "/var/log/nginx/error.log" failed (13: Permission denied)
02:38:26 web.1  | 2014/11/06 02:38:26 [warn] 15897#0: the "user" directive makes sense only if the master process runs with super-user privileges, ignored in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:1
02:38:26 web.1  | 2014/11/06 02:38:26 [emerg] 15897#0: open() "/var/log/nginx/access.log" failed (13: Permission denied)
02:38:26 web.1  | Process exited unexpectedly: nginx
02:38:26 web.1  | Going down, terminating child processes...
02:38:26 web.1  | vendor/bin/heroku-php-nginx: line 282: 15891 Terminated              tail -qF -n 0 "${logs[@]}"
02:38:26 web.1  |      15892                       | strip_fpm_child_said 1>&2
02:38:26 web.1  | exited with code 1
02:38:26 system | sending SIGTERM to all processes
```

Apparently, it can't start because it can't access log files that is owned by root user.

Next, I'm trying to start it using *sudo*: `sudo foreman start web` and getting the following output:

```
02:43:29 web.1  | started with pid 16153
02:43:30 web.1  | Booting on port 5000...
02:43:30 web.1  | DOCUMENT_ROOT changed to '/web/'
02:43:30 web.1  | Starting php-fpm...
02:43:30 web.1  | Starting nginx...
02:43:32 web.1  | nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
02:43:32 web.1  | nginx: [emerg] bind() to [::]:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
02:43:32 web.1  | nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
02:43:32 web.1  | nginx: [emerg] bind() to [::]:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
02:43:33 web.1  | nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
02:43:33 web.1  | nginx: [emerg] bind() to [::]:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
02:43:33 web.1  | nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
02:43:33 web.1  | nginx: [emerg] bind() to [::]:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
02:43:34 web.1  | nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
02:43:34 web.1  | nginx: [emerg] bind() to [::]:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
02:43:34 web.1  | nginx: [emerg] still could not bind()
02:43:34 web.1  | Process exited unexpectedly: nginx
02:43:34 web.1  | Going down, terminating child processes...
02:43:34 web.1  | vendor/bin/heroku-php-nginx: line 282: 16229 Terminated              tail -qF -n 0 "${logs[@]}"
02:43:34 web.1  |      16230                       | strip_fpm_child_said 1>&2
02:43:34 web.1  | exited with code 1
02:43:34 system | sending SIGTERM to all processes
```

Looks like it doesn't like that nginx service is running. Why is that?

I'm turning the webserver off using: `sudo service nginx stop` and trying again.

This time there are no error messages and it looks like server is running.

However, when I'm loading the webpage in my browser I'm getting the HTTP's **502 Bad Gateway** error.

From the nginx error log I can see that nginx can't access FastCGI socket file:

`2014/11/06 02:45:44 [crit] 16342#0: *1 connect() to unix:/tmp/heroku.fcgi.5000.sock failed (13: Permission denied) while connecting to upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/tmp/heroku.fcgi.5000.sock:", host: "localhost:5000"`.

The socket file is owned by `root` and nginx is running as `www-data`.

What is the reason for this, how do I fix this problem? Is it possible to run Heroku locally from my user (not the root)?

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same issue (on Mac OS, fresh install of nginx with homebrew).

I did not edit `vendor/heroku/heroku-buildpack-php/conf/nginx/heroku.conf.php` (it'd be overridden anytime the buildback gets updated, and it's slightly different nowadays anyway).

I've just fixed the permission for the error log file (chmoded it) and then run `heroku local` as normal

If you run `heroku local` as root, that will work around your error log permission error, but then nginx runs as root and php-fpm runs as nobody (in my case), hence the permission mismatch stated above.

If you fix the permission and then run `heroku local` (no sudo), then both runs as nobody, and it worked for me.

Comment: What permissions did you set on those log files?

Comment: For others coming across this - there's also a fix at the end of https://berezovskyi.me/2015/02/deploying-sample-silex-app-to-heroku/: open another terminal in parallel and execute `sudo chmod 0667 /tmp/heroku.fcgi.5000.sock`

Answer (score 0):

Your circumstance exactly like me.

The problem is the difference permission between process about nginx and php5-fpm.
Quick fix:

First:

Edit file: vendor/heroku/heroku-buildpack-php/conf/nginx/heroku.conf.php

comment:    #server unix:/tmp/heroku.fcgi..sock max_fails=3 fail_timeout=3s;

open comment and change port: server 127.0.0.1:9000 max_fails=3 fail_timeout=3s;

Second:

Edit file: vendor/heroku/heroku-buildpack-php/conf/php/php-fpm.conf

comment: listen = /tmp/heroku.fcgi.${PORT}.sock

open comment and change port: listen = 127.0.0.1:9000